# Rotate subarrays to get a sorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an array of integer `a[1..n]`, where all elements are unique. After rotation of the subarray `a[i..j]`, we will get a new array `a[1..i-1] a[j,j-1,..i+1,i] a[j+1..n]`

The question is to **find the minimum steps of rotation to obtain an increasing array** [Algorithm Problem].

Is there a low complexity algorithm to solve this problem?

Example 1. For array `3 2 4 1`, two steps are needed to sort the array.

```
   3 2 [4 1]   // rotate subarray [4 1]
-> [3 2 1] 4   // rotate subarray [3 2 1]
-> 1 2 3 4
```

Example 2. For array `5 4 6 7 3 1 2`, three steps are needed.

```
   5 4 [6 7 3] 1 2
-> 5 4 3 [7 6 1 2]
-> [5 4 3 2 1] 6 7
-> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Seems like a generalization of [pankake sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting), maybe that helps you find an optimal algorithm.

Comment: @useprxf - Just a question - what is the priority? I can find solution in `O(n^2)` time with `O(n)` rotations, but I cannot guarantee that you cannot do the same with less steps.

Comment: @libik The difficulty is to find the minimum step :) `O(n)`-rotation is just the upper bound

Comment: Then on every round you just rotate biggest number not in place to its proper place. In your example put 4,3,2,1 in turn to their proper positions. That's O(n).

Comment: @Yola - Yes, thats `O(n^2)` solution with `O(n)` rotations that sorts the array, but it does not solve the real question - what is minimum steps to do this task.

Comment: @libik I think the brute force complexity woule be `O((n^2)^n)` :(   Why `O(n^3)`

Comment: Could you scan from the right for a decreasing sequence, if you find one you reverse the sub array. Continue to find the sequence from the first decreasing sequence, if you cant find one and reach the start reverse from start to end. No. of reverses are your minimum steps.

Comment: @SamerTufail I think your method fails for example 2.

Comment: @useprxf indeed it does

Comment: @useprxf - Yep, that would be the real brute-force complexity, I messed that up and then delete the comment as non-relevant, but you were too fast :)

Comment: @tobias_k the Wikipedia article also says that finding the shortest sequence of "flips" to sort the pile was proven to be NP-hard.